# Lightning speed Changesets

Tags: deployment, change-set

I have noticed for a couple of days now that after uploading a Changeset to Production environment it becomes available for Validation/Implementation significantly faster than it used to.
Is anyone else using change sets for deployment experiencing this improvement? and if so, do you happen to know what did Salesforce change to make it faster?

Comment: I asked someone who might know. Hopefully you'll get a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Spring '20 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_deployment_availability_performance_.htm) are mentioning increased speed when uploading a change set.